# Keeping query parameters in url when returning bad request from invalid form entries

Tags: javascript, remix.run

I'm currently doing a signup page which covers different signup types which are differentiated by query parameters. Something like `"example.com\signup?inst=someUUID"`. This works well, however whenever I submit the form with any invalid entries and the page is re-rendered the query parameters are reset and so the signup form is no longer correct. Is there a way to maintain the query parameters?

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const orgId = url.searchParams.get("orgId")
  const loginType = url.searchParams.get("type")

  const school = orgId ? await getOrg(orgId) : null

  const user = await getUser(request)
  return json({ user, school, loginType })
}

//action
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const form = await request.formData()
  const formValues = Object.fromEntries(form)

  //save form values in db ....

  const fieldErrors = {
    email: validateEmail(email, schoolDomain),
    password: validatePassword(password),
  }
  if (Object.values(fieldErrors).some(Boolean)) {
    return badRequest({
      fieldErrors,
      fields,
      formError: null,
    })
  

  return createUserSession(client.id, "/test")

export default function SignUp() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>()
  return (
    <div>
                {data.school && data.loginType === "teacher" ? (
                  <h2 >
                    Teacher Signup
                  </h2>
                ) : data.school ? (
                  <h2 >
                    Student Signup
                  </h2>
                ) : null}
                <h2>
                  Enter your details
                </h2>
                <Form className="" action="#" method="POST">
                  <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="schoolId"
                    value={data.school?.id}
                  />
                {data.loginType === "teacher" ? 
                 <div>
                        <label
                         
                        >
                          School Year
                        </label>
                        <input
                                id="schoolYear"
                                name="schoolYear"
                                type="text"
                                autoComplete="schoolName"
                                required
                              
                              />
                           : null }
              // other common fields
              </Form>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `action` attribute on your `<Form>`. Remix (and the browser) will always submit to the current URL when there is no `action`.